# indexPath.row goes from 0 to 16 and not beyond

Tags: swift3, xcode8

why is the code below only displays cells from 1 to 17 ?

```
 internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 20
}

internal func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier:"Cell")


  cell.textLabel?.text=String(indexPath.row+1)
      print(indexPath.row)
    return cell
}`
```

Output :
[image]

Comment: Scary. Clean, delete derived data and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Please enable scrolling of your tableview, and scroll down cell in your output.